# Docker: Service is not running. Windows will ask you for elevated access

Tags: windows, docker

I try to configure docker to start automatically after I log on.

I have a pop up saying
'service is not running'
'Docker desktop is not running. would you like to start it? Windows will ask you for elevated access.'

[Service is not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2XNZ.png)

After I click on the start, the whale appears on the taskbar, then after a while, it disappears. Docker fails to start

If I log on into my administrative account, it also shows up, but, it starts without problems.

I have already add my account to docker-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for requiring an admin session is that the Docker client in the default configuration uses a named pipe to connect to the Docker engine and that named pipe can only be accessed by administrators.

To avoid this, you can simple allow your user 'FullControl' access to that named pipe.

You can find a Powershell module here that will fix it.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dockeraccesshelper/0.0.3

Instructions on how to use the module are here.

https://github.com/tfenster/dockeraccesshelper

Comment: Bro, i need to give you a kiss
`
$account="MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows"
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe
$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what happened for OP is for older version of docker, but if you want to be able to use Docker without having the admin privilege, just add your user account to "docker-users" group.

More info:

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/#why-do-i-see-the-docker-desktop-access-denied-error-message-when-i-try-to-start-docker-desktop

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530874/docker-how-do-i-add-myself-to-the-docker-users-group-on-windows